# Can't install Ubuntu on macbook1,1 2006 "This kernel requires x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU"

Tags: system-installation, macbook

I really need Linux for school but all I have is this old macbook.

Its a 2.0 GHz Intel Core Duo (T2500). 945 chips.

- Memory: 1 GB RAM
- Hard drive: 80 GB
- Operating system: OS x 10.6 Snow Leopard.
- Display: 13.3-inch glossy widescreen LCD. 1280 x 800 pixel resolution (WXGA, 16:10 = 8:5 aspect ratio).
- Graphics: Shared with system memory, Intel GMA 950 using 64 MB RAM. Up to 224 MB in Windows through Boot Camp.
- Front size bus: 667 MHz.
- Camera: iSight Camera (640 x 480 0.3 MP).
- Video out: Mini DVI (replaced the iBook’s mini-VGA display port with a mini-DVI display port).
- Connectivity: Integrated AirPort Extreme 802.11 a/b/h/g. Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR.
- Battery: 55-watt-hour lithium polymer battery, removable.
- Peripherals: 2 USB 2.0. 1 Firewire 400. 1 Optical diginal/analog audio line-in. 1 Optical digital/analog line-out.

How can I install Ubuntu on this?sys

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to install a version of Ubuntu that's not compatible with your machine. There are many different types of processors (CPU), and an important distinction is between 32 bit processors and 64 bit processors. You can read more about the differences for example [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001498.htm) or [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/32-bit-vs-64-bit-operating-systems/).

The processor in your machine seems to be a 32 bit processor. `i686` is a 32 bit architecture, and `Intel Core Duo` was a line of 32 bit CPUs. Today, most software is built for 64 bit processors, including the Linux kernel. Some companies or projects publish versions for 32 bit processors additionally, but those become less and less.

From a technological standpoint, the best action would be to get a more modern machine with a 64 bit processor. But that may not be realistic.

The "main" Ubuntu flavor isn't offered for 32 bit machines anymore. Also more light-weight flavors like Xubuntu or Lubuntu stopped building 32 bit relases three or four years ago.

There are a lot of others Linux distributions besides Ubuntu that *maybe* are still offering installation media for 32 bit machines. But I don't know enough about those to recommend one. It also depends on what exactly you'll need the computer for at school. Your best shot probably is to find a [Linux user group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_user_group) near you and ask for their expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 32 bit CPU, and Ubuntu does not support 32 bit architecture anymore.

Also, 1 GB RAM is not enough for recent versions of Ubuntu, even for Lubuntu, which is the lightest variant of Ubuntu. I would suggest you to try other distro like Antix, MX Linux, or Puppy Linux. They are suitable for old hardware, and still offer 32 bit releases.

Unless you need to connect the computer to internet, you can use an old lightweight release like 32 bit Xubuntu 14.04.